# Scala scripts in Windows batch files

Tags: windows, scala, scripting, batch-file

In Programming in Scala, it gives a description on how to run Scala scripts from batch files ([link](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/scala-scripts-on-unix-and-windows.html)).

For Windows

```
  ::#!
  @echo off
  call scala %0 %*
  goto :eof
  ::!#
```

I'm having a problem googling `::#!`. What does this mean? I know `::` denotes a comment and in Unix `#!` is a direction to the shell to be used, but what is it exactly here? And the `::!#`?

What exactly does `%0 %*` mean, and is it necessary to express it like this?

Is it possible to run multiple scripts from the same batch file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a gimmick, but it works. It intends to replicate Unix shell's ability to invoke a particular command to process a shell file. So, here's the explanation:

```
::#!
```

Lines starting with `::` are comments in Windows shell, so this is just a comment.

```
@echo off
```

Don't show lines executed from here on. The `@` at the beginning ensure this line itself won't be shown.

```
call scala %0 %*
```

Transfer execution to the `scala` script. The `%0` means the name of this file itself (so that scala can find it), and `%*` are the parameters that were passed in its execution.

For example, say these lines are in a file called `count.bat`, and you invoked it by typing `count 1 2 3`. In this case, that line will execute `scala count 1 2 3` -- in which case you'll get an error. You must invoke it by typing `count.bat`.

```
goto :eof
```

Finish executing the script.

```
::!#
```

Another comment line.

So, here's the trick... Scala, once invoked, will find the file passed as the first argument, check if the first line is `::#!`, ignore everything up to the line `::!#` if so, and then execute the rest of the file (the lines after `::!#`) as a Scala script.

In other words, it is not the Windows shell that is smart, it's Scala. :-)

Answer (score 2):

%0 indicates for the program name(the script file name maybe), %* indicates for the command line parameters list. %1 means the first parameter...

Comment: The same arguments are used in this Javascript batch file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999395/how-does-this-windows-batch-file-work