# What does a hash key preceded by an exclamation key (!#)mean?

Tags: scala, shell

See the following script from [scala tutorial](http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html), What does the !# mean?

```shell
#!/bin/sh
exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#
object HelloWorld extends App {
  println("Hello, world!")
}
HelloWorld.main(args)
```

Comment: [What is the meaning of !# (bang-pound) in a sh / Bash shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060419/what-is-the-meaning-of-bang-pound-in-a-sh-bash-shell-script#10060452)

Answer (score 1):

See: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs-master/manual/html/scala.html

`#!` and `!#` mark script header. All content between those marks are ignored by scala interpreter. In that section you can put shell script which will launch the actual scala script.

Answer (score 0):

The `!#` is called a "bangshe" (opposite of a "shebang").  It is a bit like a closing brace on the header statement.