# Accessing JavaScript method from a batch file

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, batch-file

I have gone through multiple post like [Embedded js in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999395/how-does-this-windows-batch-file-run-embedded-javascript) which suggest the possibility of combining batch file and javascript. My question here is-whether it is possible to use the method of a .js file in .bat file? For example-Define a js file with some methods as below -

### test.js

```
add:function(a, b){ return a+b;}
```

### test.bat

```
add(1, 2); ::Or something like add 1 2
```

### Output

```
C:\>test
```

3

Comment: if you use jscript command line arguments to select the function...

Comment: and this is applicable for jscript - not for javascript.

Comment: Okay, but first of all is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do that. The method below is a very simple one:

### test.js

```
function add(a, b){ return a+b;}
function sub(a, b){ return a-b;}

WScript.Echo(eval(WScript.Arguments(0)));
```

### test.bat

```
@echo off

set eval=cscript //nologo test.js 

%eval% add(1,2)
%eval% sub(1,2)
```

### Output

```
C:\> test
3
-1
```

In this case, the expression after the `%eval%` can not contain spaces nor special characters. To do that, just enclose the expression in quotes:

```
%eval% "add(1,2) * 4 + sub(1,2)"
```

Comment: Thanks Aachini for providing the simple method of doing the job. But just wondering if it is possible to have direct access to a particular js function like how 'mocha' do.

Comment: Currently I am using mocha to test my js method functionality, but want to execute those methods directly from command line.

Answer (score 0):

something like this (it's a verbose but this is what I can come up with)?
And this will not work with javascript but with jscript and jscript.net (but reqiores a little bit different code)

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
    @echo off

    call :add 1 2
    call :subst 5 2

    exit /b %errorlevel%
    :add [ a , b ]
        cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" add %~1 %~2 
    exit /b %errorlevel%

    :subst [ a , b ]
        cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" subst %~1 %~2 
    exit /b %errorlevel%






@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */

var ARGS = WScript.Arguments;



function subst(a,b){
    WScript.Echo(a - b);
}

function add(a,b){
    WScript.Echo(a + b);
}

switch(ARGS.Item(0).toLowerCase()){
  case "subst":
    subst(ARGS.Item(1),ARGS.Item(2));
    break;
  case "add":
    add(ARGS.Item(1),ARGS.Item(2));
    break;
  default:
    WScript.Echo("wrong function");
    WScript.Quit(1);

}
```